# LDAP Account Manager: Default profile?

Tags: openldap

I have installed OpenLDAP on Debian 11 as well as LDAP Account Manager 8.2, which seems to work well, but I have a question: On my login page, it says `No default profile set. Please set it in the server profile configuration.` - but I can't find where to do that. Where do I set this?

I have tried googling it, but it just comes up with irrelevant responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the login page of LDAP Account Manager (online demo [here](https://www.ldap-account-manager.org/lam/)), click on the `LAM configuration` link in the right top corner.

Then choose `Edit server profiles` followed by `Manage server profiles`. Here, you can add/rename/delete existing profiles and set a default profile.

Comment: Got it! But it's quite odd, I think - I only have one profile, and under 'Manage server profiles' it was listed (or at least suggested) as the default profile. Simply clicking 'Save' did the trick, thoughh, so thank you for helping me.